# Does the following inequality hold?

Tags: inequality

When will this inequality $$\max(1 + lu, 0) \geq \max(\frac{1}{l} + u, 0), l > 0$$ hold, if $l,u \in \mathbb{R}^1$?

Comment: $\frac1{l+u}$ or $\frac1l +u$?

Comment: It's $1/l + u$ only.

Comment: $l, u \in?$ Where do they belong?

Answer (score 0):

Since $l >0$ you have
$\max(1+lu,0) = l \max({1 \over l}+u,0)$.

You are asking when is $l \max({1 \over l}+u,0) \ge \max({1 \over l}+u,0)$.

Clearly if $l\ge1$ it is true for all $u$.
If $l \in (0,1)$ then it is true when $ {1 \over l}+u \le 0$ or
$u \le - {1 \over l}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\max(1+lu,0)=1+lu \text{  if  }u\ge-\frac1l,0 \text{ otherwise}$$
$$\max(\frac1l+u,0)=\frac1l+u \text{ if }u\ge-\frac1l,0 \text{ otherwise}$$

If $u\lt-\frac1l$, the inequality holds.

If $u\ge-\frac1l$,
$$\max(\frac1l+u,0)=\frac1l+u=\frac{1+lu}{l}=\frac{\max(1+lu,0)}l$$
Thus,
$$\max(1+lu,0)\ge\max(\frac1l+u,0)\Rightarrow \max(1+lu,0)\ge\frac{\max(1+lu,0)}l\ge\Rightarrow l\ge1$$

So, in general it is not true.